# Power BI Dataflow Access Token has Expired

Tags: powerbi, dataset, powerquery

I need some help understanding a refresh error for my Power BI dataset.

I have a dataset, which uses a dataflow as one of its data sources. In order to refresh the dataset, it wanted me to add the dataflow to my on-premises data gateway. (This confused me because I thought dataflows were cloud sources, but that's besides the point.)

I went ahead and added a connection. The privacy levels are all set to organizational. I entered my credentials and all the connection tests look good:
[image]

And as far as I can tell everything is mapped correctly:
[image]

The dataflow refreshes fine, but the dataset results in the following error:

Data source error: {"error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","pbi.error":{"code":"DM_GWPipeline_Gateway_MashupDataAccessError","parameters":{},"details":[{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorCode","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingErrorMessage","detail":{"type":1,"value":"Access token has expired, resubmit with a new access token"}},{"code":"DM_ErrorDetailNameCode_UnderlyingHResult","detail":{"type":1,"value":"-2147467259"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Error","detail":{"type":1,"value":"error "Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.ValueException: [Expression.Error] Value was not specified.#(cr)#(lf) at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.ValueCreator.CreateValueForNotImplemented(INotImplementedExpression expression)#(cr)#(lf) at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.ValueCreator.CreateValueForThrow(IThrowExpression throwExpr)#(cr)#(lf) at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Language.ValueCreator.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.b__0(Int32 index)#(cr)#(lf) at Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Runtime.RecordValue.DemandRecordValue.get_Item(Int32 index)#(cr)#(lf) at Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ProviderCommon.MashupResource.TryGetValue(Func`1 getValue, IValue& value, String& errorMessage)#(cr)#(lf)Record""}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.Reason","detail":{"type":1,"value":"TokenExpired"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.RequestId","detail":{"type":1,"value":"3aa09183-8c56-4adc-8b54-50ebb292feb8"}},{"code":"Microsoft.Data.Mashup.ValueError.RequestUrl","detail":{"type":1,"value":"https://wabi-us-north-central-b-redirect.analysis.windows.net/metadata/v201606/cdsa/dataflows/b48662df-312e-427a-a098-684c3c78f505/storageAccess"}}],"exceptionCulprit":1}}}

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting this error?

(Also, my gateway version is current.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem has something to do with query timeouts whenever On-Prem and Cloud data sources are combined. Not sure if this is a setting that I have control over.

I ended up moving everything onto dataflows and then turning off the data gateway for this dataset. The initial full refresh still took 2-3 hours, but I no longer encountered any timeout issues. (Obviously, incremental refresh kicks in after that.)